# I want to select all dates on clicking check box

Tags: select, datepicker

[image]

If I select any date in first datepicker and click on checkbox then values of all datepicker has to be changed to that selected one.

Comment: Where is your code. ?

Comment: I am using WPF framwork with MVVM